# Reincrement rownumbers on DELETION PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables:

```
create table invoice (
rowNumber int,
yearCreated year,
ssid char (10),
fName varchar (20),
lName varchar (20),
cost decimal (6,2),
primary key (rowNumber, yearCreated, ssid)
)engine=innodb;

create table invoiceComment (
frowNumber int,
fyearCreated year,
fssid char (10),
comment varchar (1024),
primary key (frowNumber, fyearCreated, fssid),
foreign key (frowNumber, fyearCreated, fssid) references invoice(rowNumber, yearCreated, ssid)
)engine=innodb;
```

Now in PHP I have the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) {
$del = "delete from invoice 
        where rowNumber='".$_POST['updrowNumber']."' AND 
        yearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."' AND
        ssid='".$_POST['ssid']."';";
$delstmt = $pdo->prepare($del);
$delstmt->bindParam(':rowNumber', $_POST['updrowNumber']);
$delstmt->bindParam(':yearCreated', $_POST['updyearCreated']);
$delstmt->bindParam(':ssid', $_POST['ssid']);
$delstmt->execute();

$delcom = "delete from invoiceCommennt 
        where frowNumber='".$_POST['updrowNumber']."' AND 
        fyearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."' AND
        fssid='".$_POST['ssid']."';";
$delcomstmt = $pdo->prepare($delcom);
$delcomstmt ->bindParam(':rowNumber', $_POST['updrowNumber']);
$delcomstmt ->bindParam(':yearCreated', $_POST['updyearCreated']);
$delcomstmt ->bindParam(':ssid', $_POST['ssid']);
$delcomstmt ->execute();
```

So far so good.

The problems start here. I'm trying to update the rownumbers and reincrement them. Let's say we have data like this:

```
1 
2 
3
4
```

If I delete row number 3 I get this result:

```
1
2 
4
```

Instead I want this result:

```
1
2
3
```

The code I've tried is:

```
$sortrows = "select * from invoice 
             where yearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."' and 
             ssid='".$_POST['ssid'].'";";
$sortrowsstmt = $pdo->prepare($sortrows);
$sortrowsstmt->bindParam(':yearCreated', $_POST['updyearCreated']);
$sortrowsstmt->bindParam(':ssid', $_POST['ssid']);
$sortrowsstmt->execute();

$counter='';

if ($sortrowsstmt->rowCount() > 0) {
   while ($row = $sortrowsstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $counter++;
        $rowNumber=$row[0];

        $reincrrows = "update invoice, invoiceComment 
                       set invoice.rowNumber='$counter', 
                           invoiceComment.rowNumber='$counter'
                       where invoice.rowNumber='$rowNumber' and
                             invoice.yearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."' and
                             invoiceComment.frowNumber='$rowNumber' and
                             invoiceComment.fyearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."';";
         $reincrrowsstmt = $pdo->prepare($reincrrows);
         $reincrrowsstmt->bindParam(':rowNumber', $counter);
         $reincrrowsstmt->bindParam(':yearCreated', $_POST['updyearCreated']);
         $reincrrowsstmt->bindParam(':frowNumber', $counter);
         $reincrrowsstmt->bindParam(':fyearCreated', $_POST['updyearCreated']);
         $reincrrowsstmt->execute();
   }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`xxxxx`.`invoiceComment`, CONSTRAINT `invoiceComment_xxxx_x` 
FOREIGN KEY (`frowNumber`, `fyearCreated`, `fssid`) REFERENCES `invoice)' in 
xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.php:150 Stack trace: #0 /xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.php(150): 
PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.php
on line 150
```

Now I understand what this error means. My question is can't I update and reincrement the rownumbers like this? And if I can what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't. It creates a huge nightmare when it comes to related tables.

Comment: Why do you have a composite primary key? Isn't the row number unique all by itself?

Comment: You could use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the foreign key definition.

Comment: @Barmar 
The idea is that the row numbers start from 1 for each year. So the rownumber, the year and the ssid makes a row unique.

For example:
Rownumber: 1, yearCreated: 2020 ssid: 1234
Rownumber: 2, yearCreated: 2020 ssid: 1234
Rownumber: 1, yearCreated: 2021 ssid: 1234
Rownumber: 2, yearCreated: 2021 ssid: 1234
Rownumber: 3, yearCreated: 2021 ssid: 1234

I'm not sure if I explain it well but that's the idea.

Comment: I recommend that you add a separate `id` column that's the primary key and uses `auto_increment`. Use that as the foreign key. Then you can update row number without affecting the related tables.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any other way than that I can solve this without needing to alter the table? I have alot of code using these two tables, so if I were to change the table I would need to change my stored procedures and everything on my page that is showing these two tables.

Comment: Did you try `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm reading about it now. I will try that and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Barmar I tried putting the ON UPDATE CASCADE in the invoiceComment table at the end after references xxx(xxxxx.....) and it didn't do anything. I just started getting an error when doing an insert, which I wasn't getting before. And when I do the deletion it's still the same as before.

Comment: `$reincrrows` doesn't have any of the placeholders that you're trying to bind.

Comment: @Barmar yes they do. They come from a hidden form. I forgot to include them in my post. My bad.

Comment: It has `invoice.yearCreated='".$_POST['updyearCreated']."'` instead of `invoice.yearCreated=:yearCreated'`

Comment: If you use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` you don't need to update both tables. Just update the master table, it will automatically update the child table.

Comment: @Barmar ok I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: You have your reasons for doing this, but I think most of us would strongly recommend not concerning yourself with the linear order of keys, or any perceived gaps. It is usually a pretty rare situation where such a need exists, and they are mostly always a cosmetic reason that can be satisfied in other ways. Sorry, I just had to say my peace on this.

Comment: I would generate these row number values on the fly in a view as opposed to storing them. Resetting 4 to 3 is easy, but what if you delete 3 and you have to adjust rows ranging from 4 to 1,000,000?

Comment: @Barmar it's working now! Thanks alot! ON UPDATE CASCADE worked. I just needed to remove the invoiceComment-table like you said! Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's a requirement in the project I'm creating, so I need to implement it. But I understand what you mean. Unfortunately I'm also that kind of person who wants everything to be perfect, haha. So something small likes this really bugs me. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: There are such things as bad requirements where you should push back against implementing them, and this is likely a good example. Imagine that someone comes back to you with a complaint about "invoice #3" but the invoice they have is wildly different than what's in the DB. This problem also gets exponentially worse the more invoices and deletions you have, and the "invoice number" essentially becomes completely meaningless.

Comment: @Sammitch Alright, noted. Thanks for your input. I will think about that next time I get this kind of requirements. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just use an `increment_id` column. Value can be prefix, year, increment. F.e. `A-21000001`, where `A-` is your prefix, `21` the year, and `000001` the increment.
And on creating an entity you create a new increment_id. _And yes, they will have gaps too. But you should not care._ | EDIT: just saw its required. ... yea .. good luck :p